# extraneous input 'timestamp' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 54)

Tags: sql, azure-databricks

I'm trying to convert my column of string data type to timestamp in my Azure databricks.
I'm using `10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12)` So I wrote the following query

```
Alter table convertToTimeStamp alter column FinalDate timestamp
```

My sample data looks like

```
|FinalDate            |
|---------------------|
|2/18/2021 7:20:12 PM | 
|2/22/2021 5:25:13 PM |
|4/23/2021 3:19:35 AM |
```

But I'm getting ParseException saying that

```
extraneous input 'timestamp' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 54)
```

Can you please guide me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table-manage-column), it appears Databricks SQL doesn't support this operation.

You can see there is no option to alter the datatype in the documented syntax for `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN`

```
{ { ALTER | CHANGE } [ COLUMN ] { column_identifier | field_name }
  { COMMENT comment |
    { FIRST | AFTER column_identifier } |
    { SET | DROP } NOT NULL |
    SET DEFAULT clause |
    DROP DEFAULT |
    SYNC IDENTITY |
    SET { MASK clause } |
    DROP MASK |
    SET TAGS clause |
    UNSET TAGS clause } }
```

This is consistent with the error message, which suggests it's expecting a semicolon at the 54th character (i.e. after `alter column FinalDate`).

Here's an example of an older SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74391411/23781552) that describes how it's done in pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a table like below

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE dilip_02 (
     FinalDate STRING
   ) USING delta
   OPTIONS (
     path '/FileStore/tables/dilip_02_data.csv',
     header 'true',
     inferSchema 'true'
   )
```

I have tried the below approach in pyspark to convert FinalDate column to timestamp

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_timestamp
df = spark.read.format("delta").table("dilip_02")
df_transformed = df.withColumn("FinalDate", to_timestamp(col("FinalDate"), 'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a'))
df_transformed.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("dilip_02_transformed")
spark.sql("DESCRIBE dilip_02_transformed").show()
```

In the above reading the Delta table into a DataFrame
Transforming the FinalDate column to timestamp

**Results:**

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| col_name|data_type|comment|
+---------+---------+-------+
|FinalDate|timestamp|   NULL|
+---------+---------+-------+
```

```
FinalDate
2021-02-18T19:20:12Z
2021-02-22T17:25:13Z
2021-04-23T03:19:35Z
```